# How to receive data from a raw socket in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming, raw-sockets

I am trying to create a port scanner (using SYN packets) with the sockets library (yes I know scapy would make this much easier, but I'm mostly doing this for a learning exercise.) I have crafted the packet and successfully sent it, however I'm having troubled receiving and parsing the subsequent response. 
So far I've tried the `s.recv(1024)` and 4096, as well as `recvfrom()`.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
s.sendto(packet, (dstip, 80))
r = s.recv(1024)
print(r)
```

However, I am having trouble receiving the response, I can see that the packet is being sent correctly via Wireshark, and the SYN-ACK is sent to my machine, however I am unable to properly receive and print it. Is there a better way I can use the `s.recv()` function for this sort of input? Or am I using the wrong function? 
Any help is appreciated, I'm new to the sockets library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book Black Hat Python has en example using the socket library to create a scanner, unfortunately not a port scanner. They check if a host is up, and they use a raw socket to receive data. The code is available [here](https://github.com/AllGloryToTheHypnotoad/Black-Hat-Python/blob/master/BHP-Code/Chapter3/scanner.py).

They are sending SYN-packets with one socket object in a new thread, and sniffing the replies using another socket object.

In the example they use `socket.IPPROTO_IP` or `socket.IPPROTO_ICMP` instead of `socket.IPPROTO_RAW` depending on if it is Windows or not.

For the sniffer they use the function `setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,` socket.IP_HDRINCL`, 1)` for sniffing, where `IPPROTO_IP` is a dummy-protocol for TCP, `IP_HDRINCL` is to include headers in the IP packets, and 1 is mapped to the ICMP-protocol in the code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a recent module I wrote with the help from various sources for socket IO, take what you would like from it.

```
import socket
import threading
import time    
import pygogo as gogo    

from icentralsimulator.bridgeio.read_packets import PacketFactory
from icentralsimulator.bridgeio.write_packets import WritePacket
from icentralsimulator.configurations.interfaces import IServerInfoProvider

logger = gogo.Gogo(__name__).logger
send_lock = threading.Lock()


class BridgeConnection:

    def __init__(self, bridge_info_provider: IServerInfoProvider):
        info = bridge_info_provider.get_bridge_server_info()
        self.callback = None
        self.bridge_ip = info.IpAddress
        self.bridge_port = info.Port
        self._connection = None
        self._terminate_wait_for_incoming = False


    @property
    def is_connected(self):
        return self._connection is not None


    def connect(self, callback):
        """
        The purpose of this method is to create (and hold) a connection to the server. At the same time,
        it creates a new thread for the purpose of waiting on incoming packets.
        """
        if self._connection is not None: return
        self._connection = socket.create_connection((self.bridge_ip, self.bridge_port))
        self._connection.settimeout(0.5)

        self.callback = callback

        t = threading.Thread(target=self._wait_for_incoming)
        t.start()
        time.sleep(5)


    def disconnect(self):
        """
        Breaks existing connection to the server if one is currently made and cancels the thread that is waiting
        for incoming packets. If the connection is not currently open, simply returns silently -- thus it is safe
        to call this method repeatedly.
        """
        self._terminate_wait_for_incoming = True
        while self._terminate_wait_for_incoming:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        self._connection.close()
        self._connection = None


    def send_packet(self, packet: WritePacket):
        """
        Sends an arbitrary packet to the server.
        """
        with send_lock:
            logger.debug(f"Sending packet: {packet.payload_plain_text}")
            payload = packet.payload
            self._connection.sendall(payload)


    def _wait_for_incoming(self):

        """
        Continually runs a loop to wait for incoming data on the open socket. If data is received, it is converted
        to a receive packet and forwarded to the consumer as part of a callback.
        """
        self._terminate_wait_for_incoming = False
        buf_len = 4096
        try:
            while not self._terminate_wait_for_incoming:
                data = None
                try:
                    _cnx = self._connection
                    if _cnx is None: break

                    data = _cnx.recv(buf_len)
                    if data is not None and len(data) > 0:

                        while True:
                            new_data = _cnx.recv(buf_len)
                            if new_data is None or len(new_data) == 0:
                                break
                            data = data + new_data

                except socket.timeout:
                    if data is not None and self.callback is not None:
                        packet = PacketFactory.get_packet(data)
                        self.callback(packet)
                        logger.debug(f"Received packet: {data}")
                    time.sleep(0.5)

                except OSError:  # Happens when stopping the application
                    logger.info("Application aborted")
                    return
        finally:
            self._terminate_wait_for_incoming = False
```

Note that I don't include IServerInfoProvider, or the PacketFactory here. Those are pretty custom to my application. You will need to interpret the packet according to the packet data that arrives in your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you both replies were helpful, the second was just a bit more on topic, anyways the best resource I could find for a basic packet sniffer was here http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/